# Combine Filters and getDistinctValues()

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to use the function getDistinctValues() on my filtered binding object.

Does anybody know, how I can archive this?

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
oModel = this.getView().getModel("Resources");
var oBinding = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLListBinding(oModel, "/Rowset/Row", oModel.getContext("/"));

var aFilters = [];
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Site", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.getView().byId("sSite").getSelectedKey());
aFilters.push(oFilter);

oBinding.filter(aFilters);

console.log(oBinding.getDistinctValues("Area"));
```

With this code I will get the distinct values, but the filters are ignored.

Comment: Link to the documentation for XMLListBinding? Where does that come from? Can't find it anywhere

Comment: If you ask me like that, your are right, i cant find it too. But must be similar to this:https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ListBinding But I shouldn't use it, if it isn't documented. Damn...

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that getDistinctValues() method?

Comment: I have three cascading dropdownboxes and one data Model. In the last dropdownbox I want to show only the filtered items, based on the selection of the two other dropdownboxes. For example: the first is showing the country, the second the city and the third the company.